# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Homebrewing's [first moderator election](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: farmersteve] [image: thesquaregroot]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking mdma who will be stepping down as moderator.

Since there were as many candidates as slots, this was an uncontested election and there was no voting. See also [the special election announcment](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/460/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election).

Comment: Except there were no votes to tally, and the opavote link is 404.

Comment: @user8292: Ah yes. I forgot to change that section of the template. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Welcome onboard! Glad to have you join the team!